ssh through vpn on Windows
I only have access to our Universitys Compute Cluster through a VPN connection. The problem is the VPN connection throttles my bandwidth significantly. If I want to have other things run in the background on my device (which require internet connection) I would like to be able to just connect my Terminal to my VPN, and then use that to SSH into my SSL-VPN.

You will have to talk to your university about SSH access to the device/account to perform your work.
I can only hazard a guess that you don't work in the university's IT department, as you would have created SSH access in the network yourself.  There should be someone you can talk to that can create the necessary keys and account to to grant you access to the necessary resources.
However, I feel like the VPN access was granted for that reason. I understand that access to other network/internet resources get throttled when using the VPN, as you are using the university's resources. Is there another device that you can use for those other applications or web services? That might be your best bet.

I have created a support ticket already, to see what can be done. Not gonna lie it used to be not a problem but for some reason I have been having this problem and I thought hey maybe there is a way to do this so I dont have to wait for my Support ticket to be finished.  But thanks for the answer.
